# How can i store multiple variables and a stackpanel with child elements in a xml file with WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, xml, xaml

I need to store some data( like 3-4 string variables) and also i need to store my stackpanel with all its child element in the same xml file, and later i have to bring it back showing the stackpanel and reallocating the string variables in a new ones.

How can i do that in c# with WPF?

Comment: UI is not Data. You need to store Data, not UI.

Comment: the easy way to store values File.WriteAllText("fileName.xml", S.ToString()); , where S is my variable and talking about my stackpanel FileStream Fs = new FileStream(@"MyDesign.Xml", FileMode.CreateNew); System.Windows.Markup.XamlWriter.Save(grd, Fs); Fs.Close(); ... the problem is that i dont know how to combine them in order to bring them back later in a new window.

Comment: Create a DataModel and serialze/deserialize that to populate your UI